# email Notification when new Work item is assigned in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

In the ADO I have created new project and assigned users.
When a new work-item is created and assigned to a user, I need that user to be notified via email. We have global notification rule for new work items and also individual notification subscriptions but the ADO doesn’t sent an email alert. ADO only alert when user is @ mentioned in the work item.

Can anyone please tell me why the ADO not sending the email alerts and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a project-level subscription to check the status.And make sure the delivery setting is set to "Deliver to individual members"

[image: delivery]

For more information, you could refer to: [Manage notifications for a team, project, or organization.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled)

Comment: How about this problem? Have you tried to use the project-level subscription to check the status?